# Validate rating variable, Before processing

Tags: php, regex

I have a rating variable that is sent to PHP using Ajax, I want to validate that variable.

The rating starts from `0.5` to `5`, So the possible accepted values would be `0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, .. 5`.

I'm trying to check it using `Regular Expressions`:

```
$var = 0.5;
$pattern = '/^[0-9]|[0-9.][0-9]$/';

if( ! preg_match($pattern, $var) ){
        echo 'Doesn't match!';
}else{
    echo 'Matches!';
}
```

But that would check any number, Or decimal like `1, 0.2, 10000, 1000.99`.

So how to limit that to check only if it's  `0.5, 1, 1.5, .. 5`?

Comment: use ````if````?

Comment: Then I would need to write all the possible values and loop through that array, Would it be faster/better?

Comment: `>0` && `<=5` and then regex `\d(\.\5)?` or even mod is `var` modulus `1` ==0.5 or 0. Why do it all by regex?

Comment: @Bon You actually won't need to write out all possibly values. You can use `range` and build the array. I've updated my answer with an approach that demonstrates that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just look for numbers `0-4` and the optional `.5`, or a `5`.

```
^(?:[0-4](\.5)?|5)$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Bcsl6d/1/

...or if `0` is not valid, do the same as we did with `5`.

```
^(?:0\.5|[1-4](\.5)?|5)$
```

Explanation:

Your regexs:

```
^[0-9]|[0-9.][0-9]$
^[1-9]|[1-9.][1-9]$
```

are just looking for a number numbers, or a number or `.` and a number. You need the `.` outside the character class an to be optional, then you need the number after the `.` to only be a 5 and also optional. The `0-9` also is too large, you really want `1-5`, but you can't do an optional `.5` after that range because it would make `5.5` valid.

You also could just the 2 PHP functions for this `range` and `in_array`. The third parameter of `range` is the step to increase the values by.

```
$values = range(.5, 5, .5);
if(in_array('5', $values)) {
    echo 'valid number';
} else{
    echo 'invalid';
}
```

https://3v4l.org/1LfAT

Comment: I didn't down vote your answer, May the user who did that explain the reason?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but be aware [that it matches `0`](https://regex101.com/r/lz1YxM/1) (needs [little improvement](https://regex101.com/r/lz1YxM/2)).

Comment: @bobblebubble Ah, might have misread that part, I thought `0` was valid.

Answer (score 1):

Or since you just have ten possible values, for all those who have to look at the code later and actually attempt to make sense of it:

```
$valid = ['0.5', '1', '1.5', '2', ...];

if (!in_array($var, $valid)) {
    // invalid value given.
}
```

There is no need to use a convoluted regular expression to validate something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this regex to match numbers from `.5` to `5` with trailing `.0` as optional e.g. `4.0` and `4` both will be validated:

```
^(?:[1-4](?:\.[05])?|0?\.5|5(?:\.0)?)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9GueeD/2)

**RegERx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `[1-4](?:\.[05])?`: Match numbers from `1.0` to `4.5` with trailing `.0` optional
  - `|`: OR
  - `0?\.5`: Match `0.5` or `.5`
  - `|`: OR
  - `5(?:\.0)?`: Match `5` or `5.0`
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `$`: End